# Synthax error on trying to get the first word from every line..?

Tags: python-2.7

im trying to print the first word of very line (expect the first line) but i keep getting "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'." It's from a text file i created. Here is the sentences.

```
We are hungry.
There is an apple.
There is an orange.
Now we are thirsty.
```

and here is what i got so far.

```
filename = "firstthing.txt" 
file = open(filename)
text = file.read
lines = text.split('\n')

for line in lines:
  line.split(" ",1)[0]
  print " There are the lines:"
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: `text = file.read()`

Comment: When you're looking for help resolving an exception, please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Now it is saying 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'